# How can display roles and member count of roles

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

I am trying to make a command, with discord.js, that will display the roles of a guild and member count of each role! So far everything I am trying , it returns me all time to an error !

Here is the code I am trying:

```
const roles = message.guild.roles.cache.map(role => role).sort((a, b) => b.position - a.position).slice().join('')
```

I am struggling to find a way how to display member count for each role!
I have been trying this :

```
const size = message.guild.roles.cache.get(roles).members.map(m=>`${m}`).size;
```

But it is returning an error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of undefined
```

All I want to display is like the photo:
[image: All I want to display is like the photo:]

Comment: The reason you get an error is because you pass the whole array to`message.guild.roles.cache.get()`. So the get method tries to convert the whole array into string and then find an entry which has that string with the key. Since there is no such entry, it returns undefined. You can loop over the `roles` array and call `.get()` for each of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is fetch the server roles, and sort them *from the highest position to the lowest* and map them to look like you want.

Here's an example:

```js
let roles = await message.guild.roles.fetch();
message.channel.send(
    roles.cache.sort((a, b) => a.position - b.position).map((r) => `${r.name} - ${r.members.size}`),
  { split: true, code: true }
)
```

This should send the message like the one in the image

Comment: exactly it is what I want ! thank you so much dude!

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```js
await <message>.guild.roles.fetch(); //<message> is a placeholder for whatever variable you use for message
const roleArray = <message>.guild.roles.cache.array().sort((a, b) => b.position - a.position)
var members = roleArray.map((r) => {
members.push(r.members.size) //idk if this is right
});
//Now members and roleArray will have paired indexes (roleArray[0] has as many members as members[0])
```

Sorry if it doesn’t work, I sometimes mess up .toArray() and .array(), and I didn’t test it.

Answer (score 0):

This would do it i guess

```js
function getRoleCount() { 
  message.channel.send(message.guild.roles.cache.map(x => `${x.name} - ${x.members.size}`).join('\n'));
}

getRoleCount();
```

each element of `message.channel.send(message.guild.roles.cache` has `name` and `members` property which corresponds to the role name and members with the role. `members.size` returns the number of people who has the role. Therefore the output of the function would be

```
roleA - 10
roleB - 15
```

etc on every roles in the guild